# Using Trim with Split to Text function

Tags: excel, vba

```
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=ActiveCell, DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=True, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar _
        :="/", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, _
        1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```

Is there a way to use Trim to eliminate the trailing spaces for the info that I split into columns? Here is part of the code to the macro that I'm using for the Spilt to Columns function. First timer. Thanks.

Comment: In short, no. Just trim the resulting cells after the fact.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way to trim the data is to load it into an array, trim each element of the array, and write it back over the original data.

```
Sub TrimSelection()
    Dim Data, v
    Dim x As Long, y As Long
    Data = Selection.CurrentRegion.Value

    For x = 1 To UBound(Data, 1)
        For y = 1 To UBound(Data, 2)
            Data(x, y) = Trim(Data(x, y))
        Next
    Next

    Selection.CurrentRegion.Value = Data

End Sub
```